# CvBGCodeBookModel A good explanation?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, background-subtraction

I have been running in and out of OpenCV 2.4.3 trying to figure out the extra functions and parameters that can be used to CvBGCodeBookModel based background subtraction. The documentation is not very helpful, does anyone know a resource/tutorial out there that explains CvBGCodeBookModel implemented in OpenCV along with some of its functions?

Guidance much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample in the opencv code (**samples/c/bgfg_codebook.cpp**) that uses `CvBGCodeBookModel`, it might be a good place to look.

It says the code is adapted from the book "Learning OpenCV" by O'Reilly press, so that would be another resource.

There is also [this paper](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~knkim/paper/bgs-ICIP2004.pdf) that describes the theory, not sure if that would be helpful to you or not.

Comment: It works for me, can you go to the main site (http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~knkim/) and click the link in the publications section?